# python -- IndexError: list index out of range / dividing lists

Tags: python

I'm not great at programming and I've been driving myself crazy trying to figure this out.

I have a program to calculate binding energies that stores values in lists. At a certain point one list is divided by a different one, but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "semf.py", line 76, in <module>
    BpN = BpN(A, Z)
  File "semf.py", line 68, in BpN
    bper = B[i]/A[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The relevant code is below, sorry there's so much of it:

```
  A = 0.0

def mass_A(Z):
    """
    ranges through all A values Z, ..., 3Z+1 for Z ranging from 1 to 100
    """
    a = 0.0
    a = np.arange(Z, 3*Z+1)
    return a

def semf(A, Z):
    """
    The semi-empirical mass formula (SEMF) calculates the binding energy of the nucleus.
    N is the number of neutrons.
    """
    i = 0
    E = []
    for n in A:
        # if statement to determine value of a5
        if np.all(Z%2==0 and (A-Z)%2==0):
            a5 = 12.0
        elif np.all(Z%2!=0 and (A-Z)%2!=0):
            a5 = -12.0
        else:
            a5 = 0

        B = a1*A[i] - a2*A[i]**(2/3) - a3*(Z**2 / A[i]**(1/3)) - a4*( (A[i] - 2*Z)**2 / A[i] ) + a5 / A[i]**(1/2)
        i += 1
    E.append(B)
    return E

def BpN(A, Z):
    """
     function to calculate the binding energy per nucleon (B/A)
     """
    i = 0
    R = []
    for n in range(1,101):
        bper = B[i]/A[i]
        i += 1
        R.append(bper)
    return R

for Z in range(1,101):
    A = mass_A(Z)
    B = semf(A, Z)
    BpN = BpN(A, Z)
```

It seems like somehow, the two lists A and B aren't the same length, but I'm not sure how to fix that issue.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: How long are they supposed to be? BTW, I notice that your ranges all start at one. Are you aware that `a[0]` is the first element of `a`, and `a[1]` is the second?

Comment: I noticed function `BpN` takes parameters `A` and `Z`.  `Z` is not used, but  global `B` is.  It would be better if you passed `B` into `BpN` so you don't rely on the global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, list indices start from zero and not from one.

It's hard to be sure without seeing your code in its entirety, but `range(1,101)` looks suspect. If the list has 100 elements, the correct bounds for the loop are `range(0,100)` or, equivalently, `range(100)` or, better still, `range(len(A))`.

P.S. Since you're using Numpy already, you should look into rewriting your code using Numpy arrays instead of using lists and loops. If `A` and `B` were Numpy arrays, your entire troublesome function could become:

```
return B / A
```

(This is element-wise division of `B` by `A`.)

Comment: Thank you the issue was fixed with `range(100)` and I'll most likely rewrite the code with numpy arrays after I look into it, but right now I'm just trying to make it functional to meet a deadline.